# Does a sample version of the one-sided Chebyshev inequality exist?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities, mean

I am interested in the following one-sided [Cantelli's version of the Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Cantelli's_inequality):

$$
\mathbb P(X - \mathbb E (X) \geq t) \leq \frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\mathrm{Var}(X) + t^2} \,.
$$

Basically, if you know the population mean and variance, you can calculate the upper bound on the probability of observing a certain value. (That was my understanding at least.)

However, I would like to use the sample mean and sample variance instead of the actual population mean and variance.

I am guessing that since this would introduce more uncertainty, the upper bound would increase.

Is there an inequality analogous to the above, but that uses the sample mean and variance?

**Edit**: The "sample" analog of the Chebyshev Inequality (not one sided), has been worked out. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples) has some details. However, I am not sure how it would translate to the one sided case I have above.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b. It is quite an interesting problem. I always thought that the Chebyshev inequality was powerful (since it let's you do statistical inference without requiring a probability distribution); so being able to use it with the sample mean and variance would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 31):

**Yes, we can get an analogous result using the sample mean and variance, with perhaps, a couple slight surprises emerging in the process.**

First, we need to refine the question statement just a little bit and set out a few assumptions. Importantly, it should be clear that we cannot hope to replace the population variance with the *sample* variance on the right hand side since the latter is *random*! So, we refocus our attention on the equivalent inequality
$$
\mathbb P\left( X - \mathbb E X \geq t \sigma \right) \leq \frac{1}{1+t^2} \>.
$$
In case it is not clear that these are equivalent, note that we've simply replaced $t$ with $t \sigma$ in the original inequality without any loss in generality.

Second, we assume that we have a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and we are interested in an upper bound for the analogous quantity
$
\mathbb P(X_1 - \bar X \geq t S)
$,
where $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $S$ is the sample standard deviation.

**A half-step forward**

Note that already by applying the original one-sided Chebyshev inequality to $X_1 - \bar X$, we get that
$$
\mathbb P( X_1 - \bar X \geq t\sigma ) \leq \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{n-1}t^2}
$$
where $\sigma^2 = \mathrm{Var}(X_1)$, which is **smaller** than the right-hand side of the original version. This makes sense! Any particular realization of a random variable from a sample will tend to be (slightly) closer to the sample mean to which it contributes than to the population mean. As we shall see below, we'll get to replace $\sigma$ by $S$ under even more general assumptions.

**A sample version of one-sided Chebyshev**

> **Claim**: Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample such that $\mathbb P(S = 0) = 0$. Then, $$ \mathbb P(X_1 - \bar X \geq t S) \leq \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{n-1} t^2}\>. $$ In particular, the
>   sample version of the bound is *tighter* than the original population
>   version.

**Note**: We do **not** assume that the $X_i$ have either finite mean or variance!

*Proof*. The idea is to adapt the proof of the original one-sided Chebyshev inequality and employ symmetry in the process. First, set $Y_i = X_i - \bar X$ for notational convenience. Then, observe that
$$
\mathbb P( Y_1 \geq t S ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P( Y_i \geq t S ) = \mathbb E \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{(Y_i \geq t S)} \>.
$$

Now, for any $c > 0$, on $\{S > 0\}$,
$$\newcommand{I}[1]{\mathbf{1}_{(#1)}}
\I{Y_i \geq t S} = \I{Y_i + t c S \geq t S (1+c)} \leq \I{(Y_i + t c S)^2 \geq t^2 (1+c)^2 S^2} \leq \frac{(Y_i + t c S)^2}{t^2(1+c)^2 S^2}\>.
$$

Then,
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \I{Y_i \geq t S} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \frac{(Y_i + t c S)^2}{t^2(1+c)^2 S^2} = \frac{(n-1)S^2 + n t^2 c^2 S^2}{n t^2 (1+c)^2 S^2} = \frac{(n-1) + n t^2 c^2}{n t^2 (1+c)^2} \>,
$$
since $\bar Y = 0$ and $\sum_i Y_i^2 = (n-1)S^2$.

The right-hand side is a constant (*!*), so taking expectations on both sides yields,
$$
\mathbb P(X_1 - \bar X \geq t S) \leq \frac{(n-1) + n t^2 c^2}{n t^2 (1+c)^2} \>.
$$
Finally, minimizing over $c$, yields $c = \frac{n-1}{n t^2}$, which after a little algebra establishes the result.

**That pesky technical condition**

Note that we had to assume $\mathbb P(S = 0) = 0$ in order to be able to divide by $S^2$ in the analysis. This is no problem for absolutely continuous distributions, but poses an inconvenience for discrete ones. For a discrete distribution, there is some probability that all observations are equal, in which case $0 = Y_i = t S = 0$ for all $i$ and $t > 0$.

We can wiggle our way out by setting $q = \mathbb P(S = 0)$. Then, a careful accounting of the argument shows that everything goes through virtually unchanged and we get

> **Corollary 1**. For the case $q = \mathbb P(S = 0) > 0$, we have $$ \mathbb P(X_1 - \bar X \geq t S) \leq (1-q) \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{n-1} t^2} + q \>. $$

*Proof*. Split on the events $\{S > 0\}$ and $\{S = 0\}$. The previous proof goes through for $\{S > 0\}$ and the case $\{S = 0\}$ is trivial.

A slightly cleaner inequality results if we replace the nonstrict inequality in the probability statement with a strict version.

> **Corollary 2**. Let $q = \mathbb P(S = 0)$ (possibly zero). Then, $$ \mathbb P(X_1 - \bar X > t S) \leq (1-q) \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{n-1} t^2} \>. $$

**Final remark**: The sample version of the inequality required no assumptions on $X$ (other than that it not be almost-surely constant in the nonstrict inequality case, which the original version also tacitly assumes), in essence, because the *sample* mean and *sample* variance always exist whether or not their population analogs do.

Answer (score 19):

This is just a complement to @cardinal 's ingenious answer. [Samuelson Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson_inequality), states that, for a sample of size $n$, when we have at least three distinct values of the realized $x_i$'s, it holds that
$$x_i-\bar x < s\sqrt{n-1},\;\; i=1,...n$$
where $s$ is calculated without the bias correction, $s= \left (\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Then, using the notation of Cardinal's answer we can state that

$$\mathbb P\left(X_1-\bar X \ge S\sqrt{n-1}\right) =0 \;\;a.s. \qquad [1]$$

Since we require, three distinct values, we will have $S\neq 0$ by assumption. So setting $t=\sqrt{n-1}$ in Cardinal's Inequality (the initial version) we obtain

$$\mathbb P\left (X_1 - \bar X \geq  S\sqrt{n-1}\right) \leq \frac{1}{1 + n}, \;\; \qquad [2]$$

Eq. $[2]$ is of course compatible with eq. $[1]$. The combination of the two tells us that Cardinal's Inequality is useful as a probabilistic statement for $0< t < \sqrt{n-1}$.

If Cardinal's Inequality requires $S$ to be calculated bias-corrected (call this $\tilde S$) then the equations become

$$\mathbb P\left(X_1-\bar X \ge \tilde S\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) =0 \;\;a.s. \qquad [1a]$$

and we choose $ t= \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ to obtain through Cardinal's Inequality

$$\mathbb P\left (X_1 - \bar X \geq  \tilde S\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq \frac{1}{ n}, \;\; \qquad [2a]$$
and the probabilistically meaningful interval for $t$ is $0< t < \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Comment: (+1) Incidentally, as I was first considering this problem, the fact that $\max_i |X_i - \bar X| \leq S\sqrt{n-1}$ was actually the initial clue that the sample inequality should be tighter than the original. I wanted to squeeze that into my post, but couldn't find a (comfortable) place for it. I'm glad to see you mention it (actually a very slight improvement on it) here along with your very nice additional elaboration. Cheers.

Comment: Cheers @Cardinal, great answer -just clarify for me -does it matter for your Inequality how one defines the sample variance (bias-corrected or not)?

Comment: Only ever so slightly. I used the bias-corrected sample variance. If you use $n$ instead of $n-1$ to normalize, then you'll end up with $$\frac{1+t^2c^2}{t^2(1+c)^2}$$ instead of $$\frac{(n-1) + n t^2c^2}{nt^2(1+c)^2} \,,$$ which means the $n/(n-1)$ term in the final inequality will disappear. Thus, you'll get the same bound as in the original one-sided Chebyshev inequality in that case. (Assuming I've done the algebra correctly.) :-)

Comment: @Cardinal ...which means that the relevant equations in my answer are $1a$ and $2a$, which means that your inequality tells us that for $t$ chosen to activate Samuelson Inequality, the probability of the event we are examining, cannot be greater than $1/n$, i.e. not greater than randomly choosing any one realized value from the sample... which somehow makes some hazy intuitive sense: what is proven certainly impossible in deterministic terms, when approached probabilistically its probability bound does not exceed equiprobability... not clear in my mind yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted to apply @cardinal's equation to my permutation test to determine an upper-bound for its p-value. I have 1 unpermuted dataset $y$ and and $n$ permuted datasets $x_i$. I define some testing function $F$ and apply it to my datasets as follows: $F^{orig} = F(y)$ and $F^{perm}_i = F(x_i)$. Then I apply the above inequality to the set of values $\{F^{orig}\}\cup \{ F^{perm}_i \}$ s.t. $X_1 = F^{orig}$. I also compute the z-score of permuted vs original data for comparison $z = \frac{F^{orig} - \bar{F}^{perm}}{s^{perm}}$.

[image]

The numbers in the legend correspond to different quantities of sample points.

**Rule of thumb**: If you wish to use above inequality to prove the $X_1$ is an outlier with p-value of 1% or lower, you need at least 1000 samples, and the outlier must be at least $10\sigma$ away from the mean of the rest of the points. This is kind of brutal compared to slightly less than $3\sigma$ for gaussian distribution, but, I guess, that's the price of having no assumptions

Self-check: For large $n$ and small $p$, we have $t^{min} \approx p^{-0.5} \approx 10$ for $p=0.01$, which matches with z-score being $10\sigma$

If you are wondering, p-value improves with the number of samples because when there are more points, the outlier has less effect on the sample mean and variance