# Can Chebyshev inequality be used to bound the error of the sample mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, error, mean

Can the probability of error of the sample mean, i.e., $\Pr(|\bar{X}-E[X]| \geq \epsilon)$, be bounded using Chebyshev inequality (or something similar)? $X$ is a discrete random variable with an unknown distribution and unknown variance, and $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, i.e, $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i$. Furthermore, $X_1,...,X_n$ are *iid* random samples.

---

I am not interested in approximate or asymptotic solutions. Also, I am aware of the sample version of Chebyshev inequality (particularly [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82419/does-a-sample-version-of-the-one-sided-chebyshev-inequality-exist), and [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Finite_samples)), but that seems to apply to $|X_i - \bar{X}|$ as opposed to $|\bar{X}-E[X]|$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and precisely what you mean by "bound the estimation error"? That is precisely what Chebyshev is doing (in probability). Are you looking for a bound with probability one? (In that case, the only thing you can possibly hope for is rather trivial.)

Comment: @cardinal hopefully the edit makes it clear now.

Comment: The edit does not address the basic problem alluded to by @Cardinal: the answer remains trivial until you stipulate some restrictions on the distribution of the $X_i$.

Comment: @whuber One thing I would like to know in particular is whether in the Chebyshev inequality the population variance can be replaced by the sample variance divided by the sample size. From what I've understood from Cardinal's answer to the question mentioned above, doing so is not correct. Am I right?

Comment: That's a different question. Your current question, as it is written, makes no reference to the sample variance in the probability expression it is asking about. Your best option is to edit your question so that it explicitly asks what you want to know.

Comment: @whuber Okay, I'll post a new question on that, but can you please at least confirm whether or not any versions of the Chebyshev inequality can be applied to $|\bar{X} - E[X]|$?

Comment: If the $X_i$'s are almost surely bounded, meaning that $\Pr(X_i\in[a_i,b_i])=1$, you have room to work

Comment: @Zen Using Hoeffding's inequality?

Comment: Exactly. Are the $X_i$'s a.s. bounded?

Comment: In my problem, I can actually bound $X$ such that $X_i \in [a, b]$, but that would be a different question. Also, the original version of Hoeffding's inequality seems to target only infinite populations.

Comment: But [this paper from Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=219983) claims that the Hoeffding inequality needs to be "corrected" to be applicable to finite populations.