# Help choose correct test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, central-limit-theorem

I have N random samples $x_i$ from an unknown probability distribution $A$, and 1 random sample $y$ from another unknown distribution $B$. The distributions can be assumed to be continuous and well-behaved. The null hypothesis $H_0$ is that $A$ and $B$ are the same distribution. I am interested in testing whether $y$ is large enough to conclude that $H_0$ is unlikely. Based on the above criterion, I believe the value I want to calculate is
$$p = P[X \geq y | H_0]$$
namely, the probability of randomly drawing from $A$ a value that is at least as large as $y$.

I have tried:

- Defining a bernoulli random variable $z_i = x_i\geq y$, and estimating $p$ from the resulting binomial distribution. It works fine, but it does not take account of the magnitudes of $x$ and $y$, only their rank, so maybe it is possible to do better?
- Upper-bounding $p$ using [sample Chebyshev's inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82419/does-a-sample-version-of-the-one-sided-chebyshev-inequality-exist). Again, it works, but seems quite conservative (needs $y$ to be like 15$\sigma$ away from $x$ to achieve $p\leq 0.01$)

What other options exist? Is it possible to improve the situation by some small additional knowledge about $A$ (e.g. unimodality)?

Comment: Ordinarily a p-value is based on a *statistic,* but your probability expression is not a statistic.  Thus, it looks like you need to ask about both a suitable statistic and how to use it to conduct this test.  Typically the test is conducted by erecting a [prediction limit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+interval%22) for $Y$ based on the $X_i.$

Comment: Can't I use the r.v. $X$ itself as a test statistic? Also, I think I have found a possible answer to my second question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82419/does-a-sample-version-of-the-one-sided-chebyshev-inequality-exist

Comment: If you only have one observation for $Y$, your sample size is effectively $1$ even if you know the theoretical distribution for $X$.  Consequently, the central limit theorem can't be relied on.

Comment: @jbowman I don't follow. If I know the theoretical distribution for X, I can evaluate how likely is it that a single observation Y came from that distribution, can't I? I only need CLT to determine the distribution of X, for which I have multiple observations

Comment: You never observe the random variable: all you have is a realization.  In particular, you cannot ever directly observe any probability associated with a random variable.

Comment: What does the CLT have to do with the distribution of $X$?  $X$ could have a Gamma distribution or a Binomial distribution or whatever, and that will remain true regardless of the sample size... just having a large sample size won't make $X$ Normally distributed!

Comment: @jbowman Of course, CLT only affects the distribution of the mean. I should take a nap, I'm not making sense any more. I'll review the question tomorrow